# Relationship between program size and nice value

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm currently studying program priority, I was wondering if program size has any impact on the program's nice value. For example, if a program is larger would its priority be set higher or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

> if a program is larger would its priority be set higher or vice versa?

No, this is wrong! Nice value does not depend on a program's size.

[Nice value](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/scheduler/sched-nice-design.rst) is responsible for CPU time (this is actually wrong, because it's not actually time in seconds/milliseconds/nanoseconds/etc., it's measured in percents like *5%*, *10%*, *50%*, *100%* of CPU) that a process may occupy.

In current implementation the most interesting thing is that actually it doesn't matter whether this value higher or lower. What really matter is a difference between one process's nice value and another. That is the processes that have *+10* and *+11* nice values will have the same CPU time that is *-5* and *-4*.

Thing that is really responsible for scheduling processes is [CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler)](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.rst).

More about scheduler you'll find in [Documentation/scheduler](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/Documentation/scheduler).